# how to select a user id and merge the updated user inputs in respective fields

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have a controller with **@SessionAttributes("user_email")** now i wish to do a merge operation for this particular user_email in session

> i have a dao implementation class which performs merge operation as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean mergeusers(Users users) {


        session.getCurrentSession().merge(users); //saves or updates the lawyer details //

        return true;
    }
```

> but even though i give session.getcurrentSession it merges the new user input as a new user in the database instead of merging/updating the fiel that matches the session's user_email
>
> im new to this could someone please tell me what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two options

1. populate the Id of the user before merging or
2. find the user from the database (findById) and update the data and merge it